# Is this a good implementation for rounding a Double to the nearest half?

Tags: swift, rounding

I want to round to the closest half in a `Double`. For instance, if the number is `3.76` I want it to be rounded to `4`. On the other hand, if the number is `3.74` I want it to round to `3.5`.

I came up with this code:

```
extension Double {
    func roundToClosestHalf() -> Double {
        let upperLimit = ceil(self)
        let difference = upperLimit - self
        if difference <= 0.25 {
            return ceil(self)
        } else if difference > 0.25 && difference < 0.75 {
            return upperLimit - 0.5
        } else {
            return floor(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient / better way to do this?

```
let x = 3.21.roundToClosestHalf() // 3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Map N -> N*2, round, map N -> N/2.

```
extension Double{
    func roundToClosestHalf() -> Double {
        return (self*2).rounded() / 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** floor only (thanks Rob for warning)

Here is a shorter version:

```
extension Double{
    func roundToClosestHalf() -> Double{
        return Double(Int(self*2))/2
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the wrong value for 3.76. `Int.init` truncates; it doesn't round.

Comment: Returns 3.5 in playground, how so?

Comment: "if the number is 3.76 I want it to be rounded to 4"

Comment: Oh ok, this is more of a floor then :)